# Are Bhattacharyya coefficient and total variation distance complementary?

Tags: distributions, references, distance, measure-theory, bhattacharyya

I was reading about [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures), and, as I understood it, it should measure how much two probability measures *don't overlap*. To be clear: in [these images](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bhattacharyya+coefficient&tbm=isch) Bhattacharyya coefficient is illustrated, so, is TVD + BC = 1?

If it is so, why couldn't I find it stated anywhere?

Related question: [Does maximal Bhattacharyya coefficient imply mimimal total variation distance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205153/does-maximal-bhattacharyya-coefficient-imply-mimimal-total-variation-distance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not.

I got confused by the images depicting BC. Truth is, TVD is kind of complementary to [histogram intersection distance](https://www.google.com/search?q=histogram+intersection+distance&tbm=isch) (meaning that they are complementary as long as you measure TVD trough histograms). BC is not the same as HID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If the BC is quite small (as it measures overlap between 2 distributions), this will make the TVD high meaning that the distributions will be quite different.

In the case where BC is maximize i.e. high overlap, the TVD will be minimize and the distributions will tend to be similar.